# onclick of button popup opens. popup contains input field. On save of popup, the values should be populated in multiselect dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8, multi-select, populate, input-field

```
numList: any[]=[];

addnumber() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NumberpopUpComponent, {
       width: "500px",
       disableClose:true
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {  
      this.numList = this.NoList;  //NoList is list of input value inside popup component
      this.numList.push(result);
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="addnumber()">
    Add Number
</button>
```

Comment: Why do we need `this.NoList` here, from where are you getting this list? Is this is from `NumberpopUpComponent`? Then how are you accessing it useing `this` in your component?

Comment: Thanks for responding. We need NoList because, we are assigning that NoList array to numList array. This numList array is a model in dynamic forms. This is how we access for fields. NoList is an array which is defined in NumberpopUpComponent. Whatever user gives in input field that will store in the NoList array.
Kindly help me on how best I can do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. So from `NumberpopUpComponent` you need to get NoList. When user clicks Save button you need to pass NoList and the value in textbox to the `afterClosed()` subscription.

Comment: You are assigning `NoList` to `numList` and you are pushing the response to to `numList`.
When ever you click the save button `numList` will contain `NoList` + last value from text box. Am I right?

Comment: Yess. But the issue here is it is not displaying in that dropdown. Dropdown is showing empty

Comment: Which drop down? With the code you provide I wont be able to find where your dropdown exists. Please make it clear.

Comment: we are using dynamic forms here. dropdown is directly mentioned in json. Here is the following:
{
                    "type": "dropdown"
                    "model": "value.numList",
                    "label": [{
                            "lang": "En",
                            "value": "Number"
                        }
                     
                    ],
                    "mandatory": "true",
                    "events": "", "fieldValues": ""  "minFieldLen": "",
                    "maxFieldLen": ""     "inlineStyle": ""
                },

Comment: the above model we use in code

Comment: Can you edit your question with full component code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click save button in the dialog use `MatDialogRef` to close dialog.

```js
@Component({...})
export class NumberpopUpComponent {
  noList;
  constructure(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NumberpopUpComponent> ) {}

  onSave() {
    this.dialogRef.close({
     noList: this.NoList, // pass NoList array here
     value: inputValue // pass input value here
    });
  }
}
```

**Component containing Dialog**

```js
addnumber() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NumberpopUpComponent, {
      width: "500px",
     disableClose:true
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.numList = data.NoList;
        this.numList.push(data.value);
      }
    });
```